# Dragging point does not work and throws no error

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

I´m new to testing and cypress. I´m doing automated testing of a tool which crops an image and I have an issue that cant solve.

[Here is screenshot of the tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oy5M.png)

So my code to drag one point of this tool is this, but don't work.

```
        cy.get('.point-w').trigger('mousedown',)
        .trigger('mousemove', { clientX: 5, clientY:0})
        .trigger('mouseup', {force : true})
```

Don't throw any error but the point doesn't move. And if I check the snapshot of the trigger('mousedown') seems like it clicks there.
[Look the point.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inJm4.png)

Thanks all! :D

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop has various implementations for different frameworks.
In our case move events were working only with triggering events on element itself, and continue move from `body` to destination coordinates:

```
const SLOPPY_CLICK_THRESHOLD = 10;
    cy.get('.point-w').then(subject => {
        const coordsDrag = subject[0].getBoundingClientRect();
        cy.wrap(subject)
            .trigger('mousedown', {
                clientX: coordsDrag.x,
                clientY: coordsDrag.y,
                force: true
            })
            .trigger('mousemove', {
                clientX: coordsDrag.x + SLOPPY_CLICK_THRESHOLD,
                clientY: coordsDrag.y,
                force: true
            });
        cy.get('body')
            .trigger('mousemove', { 
                clientX: 5, 
                clientY: 0, 
                force: true 
             })
            .trigger('mouseup');
    });
```

Comment: Ill tried it but it seems that it doesn't really work.